# Appcompat error while using Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-appcompat

Getting "libraries must be same version" error after adding `firebase` dependencies into `build.gradle`. How to resolve the issue with the conflicting versions?

[image]

Comment: Its not working Peter same issue  after added

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification

Comment: Thanks Peter Adding this  "implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'"  solved my issue

Comment: no problem, goodluck :D

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to downgrade my project's target version and lowered the appcompat version. Better wait till someone knows how to fix this.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        targetSdkVersion 26
        ...
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one More dependencies below error

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```